# How to restrict gust customer 3 line street address to 2 line street address in magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3.5

[image]

I didn't find any option to set address lines in admin panel

Answer (score 1):

You can find this option in Stores->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration->Name and Address Option

Where you can find "Number of lines in a Street Address". Refer Link: https://prnt.sc/ubcr4k

You can change to 2. It is valid upto 4.

Comment: Thank you for your Replay #Sheba. Already i checked that path i didn't find that option. attaching screenshot for reference: https://prnt.sc/ucxtk2